# How can I add two consecutive subscripts in xlab for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Here is my reproducible example:

```
data.1 <- read.csv(text = "
x, y
0, 0
1, 5
2, 10
3, 14
4, 15
5, 15
")

ggplot(data.1, aes(x, y))+
        geom_point(shape=21,
                   size=3)
```

The outcome is this:

[image]

But I need to change the x label to "kg H2O2 ha-1"... with the "2" subscript and the "-1" superscript.

I was able to do it this way.

```
ggplot(data.1, aes(x, y))+
        geom_point(shape=21,
                   size=3)+
        xlab(bquote("Oxigenous application ("*kg~ H[2]~O[2]~ ha^-1*")"))
```

Having this result:

[image]

But I don't want a space between the "H2" and the "O2". When I eliminate the space..

```
ggplot(data.1, aes(x, y))+
        geom_point(shape=21,
                   size=3)+
        xlab(bquote("Oxigenous application ("*kg~ H[2]O[2]~ ha^-1*")"))
```

This is the error I have:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                   size=3)+
        xlab(bquote("Oxigenous application ("*kg~ H[2]O"
```

Any help on this issue will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This seemed to work fine `xlab(expression("Oxigenous application (kg H"[2]*"O"[2]*" ha"^-1*")"))`

Comment: Perfect! It works! Thanks so much!